# Setting up applicationContext.xml for a simple Spring app in Intellij Ultimate

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I'm a complete newcomer to Spring and I'm trying to set up a simple Spring application which I'm following through an online tutorial. The tutor is using Eclipse however and IntelliJ is complaining

```
Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

....from within applicationContext.xml

My only Spring POM dependency:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
       <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

My applicationContext.xml

[image]

Do I have to setup this up from the 'Facets' context menu in Project Structure??  If so, how?

I have all the standard Spring plugins that come bundled in a typical Ultimate installation:

[image]

My project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following dependency also for Spring Beans apart from Spring Core.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Build the project once again and see whether the error disappears or not.

Comment: There is no red underline in the applicationContext.xml filename but the issue remains within the file itself

Comment: You have to define bean for Customer like <bean id="cust" ..class="complete.package.Customer"> something like this.

Comment: this is not the cause of my specific issue